# STL iterators: Prefix increment faster?

Tags: c++, stl

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Preincrement faster than postincrement in C++ - true? If yes, why is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020184/preincrement-faster-than-postincrement-in-c-true-if-yes-why-is-it)
>   [Is there a performance difference between i++ and ++i in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24901/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-i-and-i-in-c)

I got told that when using the STL and it's iterators, I should always use `++iter` instead of `iter++`.

I quote:

> Because it can only be faster, never slower

Is this true?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020184/preincrement-faster-than-postincrement-in-c-true-if-yes-why-is-it (et al)

Answer (score 13):

Yes. It is true in general. The postfix increment is burdened with the task of preserving and returning the *old* value of the iterator. That takes time and effort, which is what generally makes it slower.

It is generally true for all overloaded increment/decrement operators that implement the traditional pre/post semantics.

This topic is beaten to death. Do a search here on "prefix postfix" for a large number of more detailed explanations.

Comment: A good optimizer can often remove the copying of the old value, especially if it is not used. So "slower" should probably be "not faster".

Comment: @Bo Persson: That's why I said "generally".

Comment: No, you said "generally slower", I said "generally not faster". :-). The question is: Why use post increment if it is not faster? No reason!

Comment: "Not faster" would not need "generally". Post-increment is not faster. Post-increment is generally slower.

Answer (score 7):

You can see in this Example that was created a temp, in postfix... This more slowly than prefix, where is no created advanced object

```
// Define prefix increment operator.
Point& Point::operator++()
{
   _x++;
   _y++;
   return *this;
}

// Define postfix increment operator.
Point Point::operator++(int)
{
   Point temp = *this;
   ++*this;
   return temp;
}
```

++iter more faster than iter++., because don't created copy of object