# operators x++; and ++x; for int.Which is faster? and why?

Tags: c++, increment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a performance difference between i++ and ++i in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24901/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-i-and-i-in-c)

They say that `++i` is faster but I don't understand why.Can anybody show me assembler codes of these operators?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346450/c-what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i/3346729#3346729

Comment: This has been asked many times before, in addition to alread mentioned referenes also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020184/preincrement-faster-than-postincrement-in-c-true-if-yes-why-is-it and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223950/stl-iterators-prefix-increment-faster.

Comment: For the `int` type there will be no difference whatsoever in most cases. It's just a good habit to always use prefix ++ unless there's a good reason not to, no matter what the type. This is because for some other types prefix ++ can be much, much faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`++i` is definitiely as fast as `i++` but it **may** be faster.
The reason is the implementation.

In order to implement `i++` the implementation needs to generate a temporary copy of `i` unlike the implementation for `++i`.

But smart compilers can optimize the genration of this temporary, they certainly do for POD types.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the compiler and the situation if it generates faster code for this expression.