# In C++ which is more "EFFICIENT" on non primitive types, A pre increment (++i) or a post increment (i++)

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a performance difference between i++ and ++i in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24901/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-i-and-i-in-c)

I had an interview today and the interviewer asked me this question.

In C++ which is more "EFFICIENT" on non primitive types, A pre increment (++i) or a post increment (i++). I answered it by saying Pre increment but was not able to give the exact reason.

I have searched through the internet and found that Pre increment is more efficient. But I could not understand the reason. Can anyone please explain me the reason?

ex:

`for ( ; c.value() != 21 ; ++c)

or

for ( ; c.value() != 21 ; c++)`

Comment: and of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020184/preincrement-faster-than-postincrement-in-c-true-if-yes-why-is-it

Comment: and of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24886/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-i-and-i-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pre-increment (`++i`) is usually faster since post-increment returns the current value and then increments the value, whereas pre-increment just increments the variable.

In many situations a compiler will optimise this anyway, unless you are using post-increment specifically to use the current value and increment the value afterwards.

Comment: This has been covered hundreds of times before. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24886/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-i-and-i-in-c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24901/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-i-and-i-in-c etc. The answer is it depends, but for primitive types it's usually exactly the same.

Comment: Because at the time of posting your answer was inaccurate (it is not the case that preincrement is faster than postincrement in all cases). You edited it after that to be more accurate.

Comment: Maybe the downvote is because this answer propagates the myth that post-increment increments the value after returning the value. Post-increment increments the value before returning, but returns the old value.