# Iterate multiple maps with single loop

Tags: c++, stl

I am trying to iterate two maps with one loop. it works fine with one map. when I add second map(see code below) it gives me error "Cannot deduce 'auto' type"

both variables are of same type.

what is the best way to iterate two maps.

```
 for ( auto& insertEntry = insertedInstances.begin(),
       auto& updateEntry = toUpdateInstances.begin(); 
       insertEntry != insertedInstances.end(); insertEntry++,updateEntry++
     )
 {
    //do something
 }
```

Comment: How is iteration in parallel supposed to work - is there a guarantee that `insertedInstances` and `toUpdateInstances` have the same number of elements? Also, the code doesn't seem to be advancing the `updateEntry` iterator anywhere.

Comment: yes they both have same number of contents

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is equivalent to

```
for(int i=0, j=0; i<10;i++) { //do something }
```

so remove the extra `auto&`

```
for ( auto insertEntry = insertedInstances.begin(),
      updateEntry = toUpdateInstances.begin(); 
      insertEntry != insertedInstances.end(); 
      ++insertEntry , ++updateEntry //pre-increment might produce better code
    )
{
  //do something
}
```

you can not use same type twice with comma operator.

Comment: @MuhammadZaighum, look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24901/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-i-and-i-in-c) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020184/preincrement-faster-than-postincrement-in-c-true-if-yes-why-is-it)

Comment: @RakibulHasan, `auto& insertEntry = ...` is not good. Try to compile some code with that construct. It should be `auto insertEntry = ...`.

Answer (score 3):

You can't have multiple type declarators inside the loop. In your case you use `auto&` twice. As long as both maps have the same type you could used

```
for (auto insertEntry = insertInstances.begin(), updatedEntry = insertInstances.begin();
     insertEntry != insertInstances.end(); ++insertEntry, ++updateEntry) {
    ...
}
```

(you probably don't want to use `auto&` in this context but `auto` anyway).

Comment: I think you need to increment the second iterator at some point.

Comment: @juanchopanza: there wasn't an increment for the second iterator anywhere in the original code. I don't know what these iterators are being used for, i.e., I don't speculate what is done in the `...` part. OK, just saw the update to the question and updated my answer correspondingly

Comment: Fair enough! But I suspect it is an oversight or a but in OP's code.

Comment: is there a better way to Iterate two maps ? I have two maps with same number of content but one of them contains ids that I want to copy to the other and do some operations

Comment: @MuhammadZaighum This way seems perfectly fine to me. This kind of flexibility is what iterators and the generic `for` loop are for.

Comment: @MuhammadZaighum "one of them contains ids that I want to copy to the other" - you should think about whether those insertions will always be before the node you've iterated to in that destination container - if not, you'll have to design your code to handle visiting the newly inserted node, and also do something to ensure the check for end doesn't trigger prematurely or too late....