# In a for loop, is there a difference between pre/post-incrementing a loop control variable in terms of the total quantity of iterations?

Tags: c++, for-loop, increment, post-increment, pre-increment

When I compile and run the code below with either `counter++` or `++counter` substituted for `x`, the output is identical; in both cases, numbers 1 - 10:

```
for (int counter = 1; counter < 11; x)
{
    std::cout << counter << endl;
}
```

Originally I thought `++counter` would increment by 1 and then return the new value before for boolean expression in the loop header was evaluated. i.e when starting with `counter = 1` and using `++counter`, `counter` would have a value of 2 in the boolean expression. This appears to not be the case, as both outputs are identical rather than the `++counter` version having one less iteration, like I expected.

Reading around, it appears `++counter` and `counter++` increment `counter` by 1 at either the start or end of the loop body respectively. In which case is this not, at least conceptually, an identical action? Because the end and the start of the loop are the same thing once the loop has past the first iteration.

The only time I can see this making a difference is in the first iteration, where `std::cout << counter << endl;`should output 1 to the console if `counter++` is used (because 1 is added to counter at the end of the loop). Whilst `std::cout << counter << endl;` should output 2 to the console if `++counter` is used (because 1 is added to counter at the start of the loop).

In addition to the question above, could you please precisely explain the order in which the three actions are evaluated in the for loop header, and explain exactly where the iterations occur when using `i++` and `++i`.

Many thanks!

Comment: In short: No, there isn't any difference for the number of iterations.

Comment: See [**for loop**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for).

Comment: At that place of the loop, they are equivalent. Also note that compilers will almost certainly exchange the post-increment with a pre-increment at that place, at least when optimizations are turned on.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no difference. In older compilers, `++counter` was faster because it did not create a temporary variable but all modern compilers can optimize that out. For heavy objects with custom (non-inlined) increment operators, `++counter` can still be more efficient.

As for when evaluation takes place:

```
for (initialization; condition; increment/decrement)
    code;
```

is evaluated as

```
{
    initialization;
    while (condition)
    {
        code;
        increment/decrement;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can look here for more examples: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for

Comment: @StenSoft Cheers for the help!

Comment: A mention that in devug builds, `++` pre will be way faster: and poinlessly slow debug buikds can be annoying to work with.

Answer (score 5):

The C++ for-loop may be *roughly* considered as syntactic sugar for the following (using your example):

```
int counter = 1;
while (counter < 11)
{
    std::cout << counter << endl;
    x;
}
```

So, the initialization statement is executed first, the condition expression is executed before each iteration, and the increment statement is executed at the end of each iteration.

We can see here that using post-increment or pre-increment operators makes no difference to the loop logic, though there may be other differences (post-increment actually requires keeping a copy of the old value of the variable as that is the value of the expression, which has some associated costs, see [Preincrement faster than postincrement in C++ - true? If yes, why is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020184/preincrement-faster-than-postincrement-in-c-true-if-yes-why-is-it)).

Comment: Looks like an infinite loop to me.

Comment: x here would be replaced by ++counter or counter++. I'm following the convention suggested by the poster.

Answer (score 1):

counter++ makes a copy increase counter and returns the value

++counter increases counter and returns counter.

In loop

```
for(initialization;condition;increment/decrement)

{body;}
```

increment/decrement is the last line of the loop. So it will start the loop again when increment/decrement returns a value. So post-increment or pre-increment will not affect here. See this

[What is the difference between pre-increment and post-increment in the cycle (for/while)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17366847/what-is-the-difference-between-pre-increment-and-post-increment-in-the-cycle-fo)